# Get result from Oracle SQL query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this Java Object which I will use to store counted elements from table:

```
private DCDataObj dc;

    public class DCDataObj
    {

        private int datacenter;             //  Datacenters
        .............

        public DCDataObj()
        {
        }

        public DCDataObj(int datacenter..........)
        {
            this.datacenter = datacenter;
            ..........
        }

        public int getDatacenter()
        {
            return datacenter;
        }

        public void setDatacenter(int datacenter)
        {
            this.datacenter = datacenter;
        }

        ..........
    }
```

I use this SQL query to count the components into the Oracle table:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM COMPONENTSTATS CS, COMPONENTTYPE CT "
    + " WHERE CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID AND CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN ( "
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? " //  10
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? " //  20
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? " //  30
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) " //  40
    + " GROUP BY CT.NAME ORDER BY CT.NAME");

ps.setInt(1, 1000);
......
```

I get the result using this Java code:

```
ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
while (result.next())
{

    dc = new DCDataObj(
            result.getInt(1),
            result.getInt(2),
            result.getInt(3),
            ...........
            );

}
```

I get this problem when I execute the query:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

Can you help me how I can solve this problem?

***UPDATE***

```
The SQL query works. I get this result:

    CNT                    
---------------------- 
1                      
1                      
1  1
```

I suspect that the problem is into the return type. I suppose that I get the result as array. But can I somehow inset the result from the query into the Java object without using Array?

Comment: [Worth reading](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.in/2008/04/sql-error-ora-01745-invalid-hostbind.html)

Comment: Your SQL statement returns a result set with two columns, `COMPONENT_TYPE` and `CNT`.  Are you trying to retrieve the value for one of those columns from the first row of the result and pass that to your `DCDataObj` constructor?  If so, are you trying to retrieve the `CNT`?  Or the `COMPONENT_TYPE`?  My guess would be the `CNT`.

Comment: Yes, I only need `CNT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each line, you end with a "?" but the next line starts with another "?" without a comma.  Then you wind up with part of the string looking like ", ? ?," which is invalid JDBC syntax.  You need commas in between all your "?" placeholders.

Try this, with commas added at the end of your lines "10", "20", and "30".

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT CT.NAME AS COMPONENT_TYPE, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM COMPONENTSTATS CS, COMPONENTTYPE CT "
    + " WHERE CS.COMPONENTTYPEID = CT.COMPONENTTYPEID AND CT.COMPONENTTYPEID IN ( "
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " //  10
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " //  20
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, " //  30
    + " ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) " //  40
    + " GROUP BY CT.NAME ORDER BY CT.NAME");
```

**EDIT**

Now that I see your data, I see the problem.  You cannot call `getInt` referencing the data, only the column header name or the 1-based column index.  Also, your "COMPONENT_TYPE" is alphanumeric, please use `getString` instead of `getInt`.  That also means you'll have to change your `DCDataObj` class to have a `String` for `datacenter`, not an `int`.

Try

```
dc = new DCDataObj(
   result.getString("COMPONENT_TYPE"),
   ...........
   );
```

or

```
dc = new DCDataObj(
   result.getString(1),
   ...........
   );
```

Comment: Your call to getInt was incorrectly referencing your data instead of the column header name.  I've edited my answer to add the explanation.

Comment: I edited the code, but now I get this error `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index`

Comment: You are attempting to get column #3, but you only define 2 columns in your query.

Answer (score 0):

A colon in a bind variable or INTO specification was followed by an inappropriate name, perhaps a reserved word. You need to change the variable name and retry the operation. Did you try to get results from your query using pl/sql or SQL plus or your oracle terminal? Just to ensure you're executing the right query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no column called "DATACENTER" fetched in the SELECT statement. It should be either COMPONENT_TYPE or CNT in result.getInt call.